# Converting Java byte array into iOS NSData

Tags: java, ios, arrays, nsdata

In Java I have a byte array representation which in iOS I have represented as NSData.

Everything works fine - it's just that some access methods seem rather clumsy in iOS compared to Java.

Accessing a single byte in Java: `byteArray[i]`

while in iOS I keep using this where byteArray is a NSData:

```
 Byte b;
 [byteArray getBytes: &b range: NSMakeRange( i, 1 )];
```

Isn't there a more direct way of writing this similar to Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well considering not using a NSData Object you could transform it to a const void* like this.

```
NSdata *data = your data stuff
NSUInteger i = 1;
const char * array = [data bytes];
char c = array[i];
```

**Note**
This kind of array is read only! (const void *)

Otherwise you'll have to use the functions you already mentioned or some [others Apple provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Edit**

Or you could add some category to NSData

```
@interface NSData(NSDataAdditions)

- (char)byteAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end

@implementation NSData(NSDataAdditions)

- (char)byteAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    char c;
    [self getBytes: &c range: NSMakeRange( index, 1 )];
    return c;
}

@end
```

And then access your Array like this:

```
NSdata *data = your data stuff
char c = [data byteAtIndex:i];
```